# Edit an ADO recordset without altering the database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I am trying to add some data to a recordset before I paste its contents to a worksheet. I want to treat the recordset disconnected from the DB, thus only changing the imported data itself.

I used the method from [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?508650-Change-recordset-value), but unfortunately I end up with the error:

> Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

In short, I have a query with an empty field which I populate before pasting the rs to the ws.

Note that I have left out a lot of code. All variables are declared.

```vb
Public Function getdata(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim connstring As String
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

connstring = "omitted"
cnn.Open connstring

Set getdata = New ADODB.Recordset
    getdata.CursorLocation = adUseClient
getdata.Open query, connstring, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

cnn.Close
End Function

'----------------------------------

Sub Start()
'Code
Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet

Set rs = getdata("Select Code, '' From (values" & RegularCode & "," & RegularCodeBase & ") As AT(Code) Except Select Code, '' From astAssetTypes")

rs.Fields(1).Value = "TestValue" 'Error on this line

'Code
End Sub
```

Alternatively I could populate an array with the recordset and edit that array, but I feel that's a step I needn't to take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disconnect the ADO recordset before making the edits. However, depending upon if the recordset is actually updateable, you can still run into errors.

To disconnect the recordset, simply remove the connection:

```
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
```

That will prevent it from sending any changes back to the server.

Disconnected recordsets are still dependent on the database with regard to what's writable. They can get reconnected, and should then be able to submit the changes back to the database.

If you want to adjust things that aren't writable on the database side, I recommend moving the recordset to an array. You can use the [GetRows method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017) to efficiently move the data.